# jQuery postback focus

Tags: jquery

On my pages after a postback I am trying to return focus to a previously focused element

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.focus').focus();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:not([type=button],[type=submit]), select, textarea').focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
  });
  $('input:not([type=button],[type=submit]), select, textarea').blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
  }); 
});
```

My code looks like this and it works even for nested elements but looks a little awkward to me, I am just wondering if there is a better/more optimal way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the selector and put the `focus` trigger in the dom ready function. You might even try whitelisting the types of `input` elements you want to focus on instead of blacklist.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.focus').focus();
    $('input[type=text], select, textarea').focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass('focus');
        // To save the focused value to a hidden field
        $('#id-of-Hidden-Field').val($(this).attr('name'));

    }).blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('focus');
        // remove the focus hidden field
        $('#id-of-Hidden-Field').val('');
    }); 
});
```

However, I'm not sure how you are saving which element was focused before the postback in order to output it with the `focus` class on the new page load. If you *are* doing that somehow, then this code is fine.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You right, looks like this is what I need to do - add a hidden field and save it there, unless there is a better way.

Comment: I sure will. But if you could show me how to save the focused control using hidden field for example, as it seems the best option, I would appreciate that.